# Why not Server.Transfer why only Response.Redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having 2 text boxes and a button and a Href tag to open a calendar when clicks on it. The same i have on another page

I write a code to transfer to a particular page as follows using Respose.Redirect

```
protected void Button1_Click3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Demo/Default.aspx");//Works fine
    //Server.Tranfer("Demo/Default.aspx"); // Does not works
}
```

This works cleanly but if i use Sever.Tranfer on the second page i am unable to load the calendar control when user clicks on Href tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm

> Firstly, transferring to another page
>   using Server.Transfer conserves server
>   resources. Instead of telling the
>   browser to redirect, it simply changes
>   the "focus" on the Web server and
>   transfers the request. This means you
>   don't get quite as many HTTP requests
>   coming through, which therefore eases
>   the pressure on your Web server and
>   makes your applications run faster.
>
> But watch out: because the "transfer"
>   process can work on only those sites
>   running on the server, you can't use
>   Server.Transfer to send the user to an
>   external site. Only Response.Redirect
>   can do that.
>
> Secondly, Server.Transfer maintains
>   the original URL in the browser. This
>   can really help streamline data entry
>   techniques, although it may make for
>   confusion when debugging.
>
> That's not all: The Server.Transfer
>   method also has a second
>   parameter—"preserveForm". If you set
>   this to True, using a statement such
>   as Server.Transfer("WebForm2.aspx",
>   True), the existing query string and
>   any form variables will still be
>   available to the page you are
>   transferring to.
>
> For example, if your WebForm1.aspx has
>   a TextBox control called TextBox1 and
>   you transferred to WebForm2.aspx with
>   the preserveForm parameter set to
>   True, you'd be able to retrieve the
>   value of the original page TextBox
>   control by referencing
>   Request.Form("TextBox1").